Sentry Flutter mobile source map and source context not working
i want i integrate flutter mobile with sentry because of the source map feature , to see the dart code lines directly in the sentry board but only the stacktrace is showing is it available for mobile or only for flutter web?
tried uploading the source maps from the sentry dart cli plugin and in the project i found my source map but still not showing when an error occures only the stack trace

Hi you need to have upload_sources enabled in the sentry-dart-plugin.
See https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/upload-debug/#uploading-source-context
